# Cómo crear un Multiselect con VueJs y Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Necesito implementar un `multiselect` en la vista en la que estoy trabajando, la idea es tener varias opciones seleccionadas en el mismo `select`. He probado algunos componentes que encontré por la web pero sin buenos resultados.

La ruta y el método del controlador en Laravel funcionan bien.

El Multiselect lo tengo que alimentar desde un método que trae los datos , Si me pueden echar una mano sería genial, les dejo el código

**Event.vue**

```
<template>
   <div>
     <div class="col-sm-12">
       <select class="form-control form-control-line"> 
           <option v-for="coin in coins" :key="coin.id" value="coin.id">
               {{ coin.name }}
           </option>
       </select>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    data () {
       coins: [],
     },
    created() {
        this.getCoins();
    },
    methods: {
        getCoins(){
            let urlCoin = '/dashboard/coins';
            axios.get(urlCoin)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.coins = response.data;
                })
                .catch((err) => {

                })
        }
    }
</script>
```

La idea es lograr esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo `Laravel 5.6` y `VueJS 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede utilizar esta [librería `vue-multiselect`](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/)  para lograr el resultado esperado, en su página está la configuración básica. Y como está usando Single File Component será más sencillo aún.

Las partes básicas es `:options` que contendrá el array que se obtiene desde PHP y es asignado a `coins` después de haberse montado el componente *(mounted())* , como posiblemente se añadirá a un petición posterior quizá, se emplea `v-model` para enlazar datos , esta contendrá los elementos seleccionados.

`Label` , será lo que se mostrará simulando el `text` de un `option` , `track-by` simulando al `value` de un `option`

En primer lugar debe instalar por medio de `npm` la librería o por un `cdn`

```
npm install vue-multiselect --save
```

Luego ya será posible utilizarlo en el componente *(los nombres de las propiedades coins y coin ya queda a su preferencia)*

**Componente.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <multiselect
        v-model="coin"
        :options="coins"
        :multiple="true"
        label="name" 
        track-by="id"
        placeholder="Seleccione uno o más Coin">
        </multiselect>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                coins: [],
                coin : '',
            }
        },
        components: { Multiselect },
        mounted(){
            this.getCoins();
        },
        methods  : {
            getCoins(){
                axios.get('/dashboard/coins')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.coins = response.data;
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- Estilos de la libreria -->
<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

Comment: Excelente, lo había probado antes pero no me había resultado, ahora tengo problemas de estilo con este componente. Muchas gracias

Comment: @Felipe ¿Qué problemas de estilo? si añadió el CSS correctamente no debería fallar . Saludos

Comment: Lo que sucede es que estoy ocupando un template hecho en material design y el css de vue-multiselect está en bootstrap por lo tanto al momento de mostrar el input select en la vista, este no muestra las opciones a seleccionar ni la opción de búsqueda, pero si lo dejo sin el estilo del compomente, este funciona pero horrible.

Comment: @Felipe ahh entiendo conflicto de estilo , a ese tipo de problemas se refería. lamentablemente no tengo una solución para eso sin más contexto. Pero estoy seguro que podrá resolverlo

Comment: te pasaste con la ayuda, muchas gracias!